# Bind a method to text box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to `wpf`. I have a method named ABC which returns max id from the database table. I want to bind this ABC to text box in `Xaml`.

```
public Int32 ABC()
{
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
   con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
   if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
   {
      con.Open();
   }
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "select (max(uhid)) from patients"; 
   cmd.Connection = con;
   Int32 k = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
   return k + 1; // want to assign this value
}
```

Comment: If your problem is binding string representation of this number to XAML, the code you show is seems irrelevant based on your problem because it seems you _already_ get your numeric value successfully. If not, please explain your problem more specific.

Comment: You won't be able to do that directly. What you need to do is set a DP or property (and notify UI of change) each time you execute ABC and then Bind this property to your TextBox.Text property

Comment: Soner, this is the code behind file code. eg if k=4 then what is procedure to bind it to Text.text in Xaml. Such as like Text="{Binding.......}" etc. I want to know Xaml file code.

Answer (score 1):

Let me assume `txtMaxId` be your `TextBox`. you can simply assign the return value of this function `ABC()` to the TextBox as Like the following:

```
  txtMaxId.Text = ABC().ToString();
```

If You are using [`MVVM`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level) them assign them to the Property that bound to the TextBox. The Property may looks like the following:

```
 public string MaxId
    {
        get { return ABC().ToString(); }           
    }
```

Comment: i want to know Xaml code... like  <TextBox Name="txtMaxId" Text="{Binding......}" etc.

Comment: Include the defined property in your model class, and bind them in xamal as you said in the comment

Comment: Sir is there any other method to bind it to text box using only xaml...